# How can I load a WPF (xaml) window inside of another WPF windows in a Panel?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is this possible?

I used a Frame control and:
show(ex:showwindow.xaml)

But I get this error:

> root element is not valid for navigation

Comment: change second xaml as page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure you can navigate (show) a window by using:

YourFrame.Navigate(YourWindow);

However I don't like much this multi-window approach, better create some user controls for segmenting your application.

Answer (score 1):

It is more common to use the Page class with the Frame control. Windows, in WPF are the top level items, with their own titlebar, chrome etc.   Also, the Page can tap into the NavigationService provide by the framework.
[more info about Navigation from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(VS.85).aspx)