# Can I insert a Window into another Window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two Window (name: window1 \ window2) whether it is possible to insert them in another Window (window3). What would have once been seen window1 \ window2, buyout lie window3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not possible. But if you separate the content of the windows out into separate `UserControl`s, then it is easy to include those `UserControl`s inside another `Window`.

Comment: Theanks, I thought that it is possible that there are Frames

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Frame.  Then load a UserControl or Page into the frame.  You cannot put a Window within the Frame however.

The benefit of use a Page is that you gain access to the NavigationService.  NavigationService gives you a forward and back stack history of the pages your user visits.
Here's [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913057/how-can-i-load-a-wpf-xaml-window-inside-of-another-wpf-windows-in-a-panel/2915623#2915623) discussing a similar question.